# RestSharp is throwing a bad request on a GET call, but is missing response body

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am making a GET call to an external REST API. I was putting in a parameter incorrectly and was getting an HttpRequestException. When catching the exception the only details it returns are:

Request failed with status code BadRequest

When monitoring the traffic using Fiddler I can see the server was returning a json message in the body explaining why the call failed.

Is there anyway to access this message from RestSharp?

I am using .net 6 and RestSharp version 108.0.2

Comment: Did you check the response's `Content` property? We deserialize it like this in our projects: `var responseError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseError>(response.Content);` if the request was unsuccessful.

Comment: because it throws an exception, the response never gets set.

Is there a way to make it not throw an exception on errors? I tried setting client.options.ThrowOnAnyError to false, but it still throws exceptions

Comment: Which of the methods are you using? `ExecuteAsync` and it's overloads don't throw, only the extensions do: https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#making-a-call There is a section in the documentation for error handling: https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html

Comment: @Julian thank you this was the fix for me, using ExecutePostAsync<> instead of PostAsync<>

Answer (score 0):

you must set `ThrowOnAnyError` from `RestClientOptions` to `false` :

```
private async Task<T?> SendRequest<T>()
        {
            string url = "your request url";
            var options = new RestClientOptions(url)
            {
                ThrowOnAnyError = false,
                MaxTimeout = 6000
            };
            var client = new RestClient(options);
            var request = new RestRequest().AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.Method = Method.Post;
            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request);
            return response.Data;
        }
```